# jQuery datepicker disabled dates - multiple ranges

Tags: php, jquery, datepicker, date-range

im a javascript / jQuery n00b so bear with me

I have a table in the database that contains multiple rows with startdate & enddate columns

I have on the page a datepicker jquery element

What I need it to do is on the page load check the database table and all the dates from startdate to enddate to be disabled
I have the below which would do individual dates however I dont know how to get it to loop and disable multiple entries ( ranges - from date to date )

For example 24-4-2017 to 26-4-2017 disabled also 30-4-2017 to 17-5-2017 disabled

so multiple ranges need to be disabled

Code I have so far below, please help guys Ive been racking my brains over this for 2 days now and have severe code block

```
        var disabledDays = ["22-04-2017"]; // M-DD-YYYY Format

        /* utility functions */
        function nationalDays(date) {
            var m = date.getMonth(), d = date.getDate(), y = date.getFullYear();
            //console.log('Checking (raw): ' + m + '-' + d + '-' + y);
            for (i = 0; i < disabledDays.length; i++) {
                if($.inArray((m+1) + '-' + d + '-' + y,disabledDays) != -1 || new Date() > date) {
                    //console.log('bad:  ' + (m+1) + '-' + d + '-' + y + ' / ' + disabledDays[i]);
                    return [false];
                }
            }
            //console.log('good:  ' + (m+1) + '-' + d + '-' + y);
            return [true];
        }

        /* 
        Above 2 are probably redundant because BaT are open Bank Holidays
        and also open weekends so ..
        */

        /* 
        Create DatePicker 
        Change MaxDate below to show more months
        */
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery('#date').datepicker({
                minDate: new Date(2017, 0, 1),
                maxDate: new Date(2017, 6, 31),
                dateFormat: 'DD, MM, d, yy',
                constrainInput: true,
                beforeShowDay: nationaldays
            });
        });
```

Comment: can u do a fiddle

Answer (score 1):

Just compare the day that is currently rendering with disabled dates range.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var startDisabledDates = new Date(2017, 03, 10),
    endDisabledDates = new Date(2017, 03, 20);

  $("#date").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(day) {
      var isSelectable = day < startDisabledDates || day > endDisabledDates;
      return [isSelectable];
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="date">
```